# Laravel Eloquent: Multiple Relationships between two Models, One-to-One AND One-to-Many

Tags: laravel, pivot, eloquent, one-to-many, one-to-one

I am quite new to both, Laravel and Eloquent and while the basics are getting along, I am researching and trying for some time to get this to work:

I have got a User model and a Character model (World of Warcraft players might relate to the issue), a User has many Characters and a Character belongs to exactly one User.

I want to store additional information about this relationship (wether this Character is the User's MAIN character or one of many TWINK characters), so I tried implementing a pivot table with an additional field (*role*), but I can't get it to work.

The **migrations** are as follows:

```
Schema::create('users', function ($table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('username')->unique();
    $table->timestamps();
});

Schema::create('characters', function($table)
{
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->timestamps();
    $table->string('name');
});

Schema::create('characters_users', function($table)
{
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
    $table->integer('character_id')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
    $table->foreign('character_id')->references('id')->on('characters');
    $table->string('type')->default('MAIN'); // can be 'MAIN' or 'TWINK'
});
```

In the **Characters Model**, I have defined the following:

```
public function user() 
{
    return $this->hasOne('User', 'characters_users.user_id');
}
```

In the **Users Model** I have defined the following:

```
public function main() 
{
    return $this->hasOne('Character', 'characters_users.character_id', 'id')->where('characters_users.role', '=', 'MAIN');
}

public function twinks()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Character', 'characters_users.character_id', 'id')->where('characters_users.role', '=', 'TWINK');
}
```

Now I am trying to setup an example relationship, I get both a user and a character and want to say: This is the main character of this user:

```
$user = User::find(1)->first();

$char = Character::whereName('Bruise')->first();

// assign this char as main to the user
$user->main()->save($char);
```

The error message is:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'character_id' in 'field list' (SQL: update `characters` set `updated_at` = 2014-09-05 12:30:58, `character_id` = 1 where `id` = 47)
```

because - of course, it's a one-to-one relationship - Eloquent searches for the corresponding fields to update not in the pivot table, but in the tables of the character resp. user.

**What I want to achieve**

- Setting a character as MAIN to a user
- Setting characters as TWINK to a user
- Querying "What's the users MAIN character, what are his/her TWINK characters?"

Is there a better, smarter way to do this instead of using a pivot table, am I completely off-track in this issue?

Comment: Being a one to many relationship, I'd just add a column status to characters table, and set it to different values depending on the char being main or twink

Comment: Actually, that is a bright idea since I already got a 'rank' attribute in the Character model with defines (by Definition of the guild leader) that a Character with a specific rank is either a twink or a main. But I will think through it, if I add two additional columns to Characters (user_id and role) to reflect this behaviour. Dead simple, on the first glance...

Comment: I think I found a workaround based on your suggestions, but since I did not manage to "set it to different values depending on the char being main or twink", I will leave the question open. I indeed use the "rank" property of Character to define twink or main, but this is not generally applicable, our guild uses this scheme, but others might not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a column role to characters table

```
    Schema::table('characters', function($table)
{
    $table->tinyInteger('role')->unsigned()->nullable()->default(0);
});
```

When you insert the char, if it's Main set it to 1, if its twink leave it to 0. Later when you want to retrieve the main or twinks from the User just use $user->main or $user->twinks

```
//model User

public function main() 
{
    return $this->hasMany('Character')->where('role', '=', 1);
}

public function twinks()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Character')->where('role', '=', 0);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I will try this out, too. It should be `->where('role', '=', 1);`, right?